# Juno/Atom Python version different from terminal and REPL Python version

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor, juno-ide

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and my version of Python points to version 3.5, however the one in Atom points to 2.7. Does anybody know how I can change that?

So the `python --version` in terminal gives me:

```
Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)
```

and `;python --version` in Atom's console gives me:

```
Python 2.7.12
```

I use Atom for Julia.
I am using Juno and PyCall.

Comment: I don't know that there is a built-in Python console in Atom. Have you installed a Python package or a terminal package? It is likely that you need to set the Python path somewhere in the package settings.

Comment: It's not a built in python console. I have looked into julia settings, somewhere so that I can find some python paths, but no luck so far

Comment: Can you clarify what Julia has to do with your question?

Comment: The problem statement is clear in the text above. It sure is some path that is directed to a different python version. But I do not know which package it is. I am using Atom specifically for Julia, and I have several Julia packages that have dependencies on Python. Moreover the question also has the tag:atom-editor, if it is not Julia related.

Comment: I disagree. The problem statement is completely confusing. You appear to be asking about a Python console in Atom, but have for some reason tagged the question with `julia-lang`. If you are using Atom for Julia, what is the connection between Julia and Python? Are you using Juno and PyCall or something?

Comment: I am using Juno and PyCall. I do not know the python console, In Atom it is called console under Julia tab. And the julia related packages are installed via Juno, that is true.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specify the version of Python used by PyCall, you can find help in the documentation [here](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl#specifying-the-python-version).

I am not certain if that is your actual problem, though, since I think that `;cmd` should be shelling out to the terminal. I would have thought it would be the same as running `cmd` in the terminal, and be unrelated to PyCall. I might be wrong, though.